# LinkedIn APi Data Discrepency

Tags: linkedin-api

We are getting different data for same company post with 2 unique endpoints.

For endpoint - https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/4822304/updates/key=UPDATE-c4822304-6378756278751109120/likes?format=json. It is giving 1 like

But when we are hitting historical-status-update-statistics endpoint for stats

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/4822304/historical-status-update-statistics:(like-count,share-count,click-count,engagement,impression-count,time,comment-count)?time-granularity=day&start-timestamp=1517443200000&update-key=UPDATE-c4822304-6378756278751109120&format=json. we are getting 0 like

Here we are fetching the data for the last 3 months, however organisation have made this post 1 month back only it should fetch the lifetime data and should return 1 like.